# Windows shortcut to specific browser tab?

Tags: windows, browser, tabs, shortcut

I have a desktop shortcut to a specific URL... works great.  What I'm trying to solve is for that shortcut NOT to open a new tab when I click on it.  Instead, hoping to figure out a way that the shortcut returns to the tab for that site which is already open.

Clearly that won't happen through a straight shortcut, but perhaps there is a way through invoking a script which searches for available tabs and activates the match.  If no match, then the tab is opened.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: This can be solved for chrome fairly easy but I'm unsure what browser you're using.

Comment: Yes, Chrome would be my first choice.